# Where to set GPS accuracy

Tags: ios, swift, gps, locationmanager

This is my first time working with the GPS for iPhone.  Do you set the accuracy once, say in `viewDidLoad()`, or do you have it continually set, say inside the `locationManager(: didUpdateLocations: )` method?

Comment: I found that if I do this prior to calling startUpdateLocations (put in viewDidLoad), seems to work....

Answer (score 0):

You just set it once when you create the `CLLocationManager` instance.

```
someVar = CLLocationManager()
someVar.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer // Or whatever value
```

Comment: Thank you rmaddy!  I don't quite follow.  I created the CLLocationManager instance with an object level variable.  I use that object as a parameter for my didUpdateLocations method, but other than in viewDidLoad, how/where would I set it?

Comment: See my updated answer. Just set the `desiredAccuracy` once wherever you are creating the location manager.

Comment: ...or perhaps when I ask/get permission to use and turn on .startUpdatingLocation?

Comment: Thanks for the update rmaddy....  I just get an error if I try to set it outside of a method:

Comment: Why would you be putting this code outside of a method? Just add the line to set the `desiredAccuracy` after your previously existing call to `CLLocationManager()`.

Comment: Thanks again rmaddy.  I'm new to this and I may have a larger picture mis-code.  I created the CLLocationManager object outside a method, and with my class-properties since I need to use it in several methods, including the locationManager (:didUpdateLocations) and locationManager(:didFailWithError), as well as when I am requesting permission to use GPS.  I may just need to study up a bit more on the CLLocationManager.

Comment: It would help your question if you updated your question with relevant code showing how/where you create the `CLLocationManager`.